# Which is the query i should do so that i could fetch the previous from last row?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to read the last 3 rows of my table seperate and then place them in 3 different div's of a slider. The problem is that i cant use 'where id=xxx' because i insert rows dynamically every time that i make a post item.

if i use query('select * from news order by id desc limit 3') and then a loop while ($result->fetch_assoc()) then i have the last 3 rows.

My problem is that i want to place every row in a different div so that i will have 3 divs.
I suppose i must do 3 different queries for that but i dont know how.

I have this one right now.

```
$result = $myDb->query('select * from news order by id desc');

    while ($nI = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $title = $nI['title'];
    $date = $nI['date'];
    $author = $nI['author'];
    $mainobjective = $nI['mainobjective'];
    $contents = $nI['contents'];
    $keywords = $nI['keywords'];
```

and then i have my html where with the use of echo i place every variable in the div i want.

Comment: i understood only the 1st paragrah. please be more clear

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem you are describing is more with your PHP code, that you haven't posted, than your MySQL. Don't read them separately. Use a single query to get all 3 and then iterate through them separately with PHP.

You can use the query you already had:

```
$result = $myDb->query('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3');
```

Make sure you are placing the results in separate containers in PHP:

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo "<div>".$row."</div>";
}
```

Comment: i added my php code. i could not understand how i can "echo" for example the columns of the previous from last row so that i have only these one in my div. i dont know if i am clear enough.